# CodeSign error in simulator pod libs

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator, code-signing

I was implementing a share extension. Out of nowhere an error occurs when I try to build the project for iOS simulator:

> CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Static Library' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.4'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged.

The error appears on most included CocoaPods libraries:

[image]

It works perfectly fine on my iPhone 6.

**What have I done before the error occurred**

I merged a branch into another branch (git).

**What have I tried to solve the error**

- Reverting the branch: no effect
- deleting Pods directory and Pod.lock file and install pods again: no effect

**UPDATE**

I downloaded the iOS simulator 8.3 and I get the identical error (... in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.4' ...).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Xcode installation was really broken. I deleted Xcode and installed it again. It works, now.